# Facebook 'like' button's mini pop up keeps closing before I can 'like' it

Tags: facebook, wordpress, og-meta

Tried to add a facebook like button which worked ok earlier, I have installed a plugin for wordpress to display the correct thumbnail when its shared on timeline. The problem is when I refreshed the sites thumbnail image using facebooks lint/debug tool (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) I am not unable to actually 'like' the site.

When I click it a pop asked me to sign in which is fine, but the 2nd pop up 'where you can type a message along with your like) closes itself when I click it, I have no idea what is causing this, anyone shared the same experience or have any idea what may be causing it? Or do I have to wait until Facebook scrapes the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working today after another refresh on facebooks URL debug tool, seems random.